# Accessing embedded SVG through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an SVG document that I've placed in my HTML file using the `<embed>` tag. I would like to access the document using Javascript and then link elements within the documents to javascript event handlers. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <embed id="embed" src="resources/Home.svg" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;"/>
  </body>
  <script src="MapInteractivity.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var svgObject = document.getElementById('embed');
var svgDoc

svgObject.addEventListener("load",function() {
      svgDoc = svgObject.contentDocument;
      alert("SVG contentDocument Loaded!");
 }, false);
var maryland = svgDoc.getElementById("Maryland");

maryland.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
    event.target.style.color = "purple";

    setTimeout(function() {
    event.target.style.color = "";
    }, 500);
}, false);
```

The issue that I'm having is that svgDoc always evaluates to undefined. I've tried using different methods such as `getSVGDocument()` to access the embedded document object, but to no avail. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Are you opening the .html running a local web service?
Otherwise the browser will raise a security exception and won't access the SVG document.

You can start a local web service using i.e. node or python.

To start your local web service in python you can run from your filepath:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

And then open it in the browser from: http://localhost:8000

Comment: This, in conjunction with Paul LeBeau's answer, solved the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `svgDoc` until it is defined.  You are partly doing the right thing, but you have to put the rest of the initialisation inside the load event handler also.

```
svgObject.addEventListener("load",function() {

      svgDoc = svgObject.contentDocument;
      alert("SVG contentDocument Loaded!");

      var maryland = svgDoc.getElementById("Maryland");

      maryland.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
          event.target.style.color = "purple";

         setTimeout(function() {
             event.target.style.color = "";
         }, 500);
      }, false);

}, false);
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked, but I had to use getSVGDocument() rather than contentDocument. I also had to set up a local webserver as suggested by @lessmore.

Comment: To work cross browser, you will need to use both.  Try `contentDocument` first, and fall back to `getSVGDocument()` for browsers that don't support `contentDocument`.

Comment: I will try this. It seems that contentDocument doesn't work with the embed tag though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the SVG object, if embedded, is actually part of the current DOM. You probably need the `<svg />` element. If you need to get it's contents from another file, either you embed it server side, or you need to open the file using an XMLHttpRequest ("ajax").

Also, be sure to get familiar with namespaces, as the SVG elements lives in another namespace than the HTML elements. This could save you some head aches :)